# SSL error received even though "ssl" is set to "false"

Tags: rest, elasticsearch, logstash, elasticsearch-plugin

Here is the `input` segment of my `logstash.conf`:

```
input {
    http {
        host => "127.0.0.1"
        port => 31311 
        ssl => false
    }
}
```

I have an index named `twitter_new`. I want to send a `DELETE` request via cURL to remove the entire index. This is my cURL command:

`C:\Users\Me\Downloads\curl-7.64.1-win64-mingw\bin> .\curl.exe -XDELETE "https://127.0.0.1:9200/twitter_new"`

Here is the response:

`curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number`

How can I fix this?

**N.B.:** The SSL error is only encountered when I send `DELETE` requests -- I can successfully send `PUT` and `POST` requests.

Answer (score 0):

It should not matter what type of request is being made. Try to change from `https` to `http` on the curl request, since SSL is set to false. Changing this should work.
Also check if you dont have a very old version of curl with `curl --version` and update if needed.